# Not compiling with OpenCV, saving to predictions.png instead

Tags: opencv3.0, yolo, darknet

**OPENCV is not detecting or compiling please help me anyone**

I am using yolov3 for object detection using darknet code everything works fine and i set the *make* file with 
**opencv=1**
but still the same error occurs
[[image]]

Comment: Please provide more detail and your code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, to solve this,

1. Check if opencv path is present or not when u use cmake
       (Opencv_DIR), if not provide the path
       .. C:\Users\nimes\OpenCV\build\install\x64\vc16\bin then configure
       and generate.
2. Provide the same path to your system environment variable.
3. Now use visual studio opening Darknet.sln , run All_Build -> build and then provide the path by
   right click darknet -> properties, c/c++ -> additional include directories, similar to linker, now right click Install -> build
4. Now run the command in command prompt and opencv will up running.